# Keep getting TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null. Actionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null.
at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/addChild()
at ChristmasGame_fla::MainTimeline/frame4()
at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndStop()
at ChristmasGame_fla::MainTimeline/onClickMenu2()
```

I have a frame which has childs added using Actionscript. From this menu there are 7 levels that each when clicked use gotoAndStop() to play the level selected.

If I select level1 it's fine, but anything 2-7 gives the error above. No idea why, any help please?

Extremely messy code below: Will be cleaned up once error is solved!

```
stop();

var day1click:Day1Click = new Day1Click();
var day2click:Day2Click = new Day2Click();
var day3click:Day3Click = new Day3Click();
var day4click:Day4Click = new Day4Click();
var day5click:Day5Click = new Day5Click();
var day6click:Day6Click = new Day6Click();
var day7click:Day7Click = new Day7Click();
var menubg:MenuBG = new MenuBG();
var menutitle:MenuTitle = new MenuTitle();

addChild(menubg);
addChild(menutitle);
menutitle.x = 338.80;
menutitle.y = 71.25;
addChild(day1click);
day1click.x = 332.80;
day1click.y = 208.5;
addChild(day2click);
day2click.x = 567.80;
day2click.y = 208.50;
addChild(day3click);
day3click.x = 796.80;
day3click.y = 208.50
addChild(day4click);
day4click.x = 334.80;
day4click.y = 362.10;
addChild(day5click);
day5click.x = 567.80;
day5click.y = 362.95;
addChild(day6click);
day6click.x = 797.80;
day6click.y = 362.95;
addChild(day7click);
day7click.x = 567.80;
day7click.y = 506.75

day1click.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickMenu1);
function onClickMenu1(event:MouseEvent):void{
    removeChild(menubg);
    removeChild(menutitle);
    removeChild(day1click);
    removeChild(day2click);
    removeChild(day3click);
    removeChild(day4click);
    removeChild(day5click);
    removeChild(day6click);
    removeChild(day7click);
    day1click.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickMenu1);
    day2click.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickMenu2);
    day3click.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickMenu3);
    day4click.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickMenu4);
    day5click.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickMenu5);
    day6click.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickMenu6);
    day7click.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickMenu7);
    gotoAndStop('day1');
}

day2click.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickMenu2);
function onClickMenu2(event:MouseEvent):void{
    removeChild(menubg);
    removeChild(menutitle);
    removeChild(day1click);
    removeChild(day2click);
    removeChild(day3click);
    removeChild(day4click);
    removeChild(day5click);
    removeChild(day6click);
    removeChild(day7click);
    day1click.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickMenu1);
    day2click.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickMenu2);
    day3click.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickMenu3);
    day4click.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickMenu4);
    day5click.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickMenu5);
    day6click.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickMenu6);
    day7click.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickMenu7);
    gotoAndStop('day2');
}

day3click.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickMenu3);
function onClickMenu3(event:MouseEvent):void{
    removeChild(menubg);
    removeChild(menutitle);
    removeChild(day1click);
    removeChild(day2click);
    removeChild(day3click);
    removeChild(day4click);
    removeChild(day5click);
    removeChild(day6click);
    removeChild(day7click);
    day1click.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickMenu1);
    day2click.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickMenu2);
    day3click.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickMenu3);
    day4click.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickMenu4);
    day5click.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickMenu5);
    day6click.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickMenu6);
    day7click.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickMenu7);
    gotoAndStop('day3');
}

day4click.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickMenu4);
function onClickMenu4(event:MouseEvent):void{
    removeChild(menubg);
    removeChild(menutitle);
    removeChild(day1click);
    removeChild(day2click);
    removeChild(day3click);
    removeChild(day4click);
    removeChild(day5click);
    removeChild(day6click);
    removeChild(day7click);
    day1click.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickMenu1);
    day2click.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickMenu2);
    day3click.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickMenu3);
    day4click.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickMenu4);
    day5click.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickMenu5);
    day6click.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickMenu6);
    day7click.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickMenu7);
    gotoAndStop('day4');
}

day5click.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickMenu5);
function onClickMenu5(event:MouseEvent):void{
    removeChild(menubg);
    removeChild(menutitle);
    removeChild(day1click);
    removeChild(day2click);
    removeChild(day3click);
    removeChild(day4click);
    removeChild(day5click);
    removeChild(day6click);
    removeChild(day7click);
    day1click.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickMenu1);
    day2click.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickMenu2);
    day3click.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickMenu3);
    day4click.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickMenu4);
    day5click.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickMenu5);
    day6click.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickMenu6);
    day7click.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickMenu7);
    gotoAndStop('day5');
}

day6click.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickMenu6);
function onClickMenu6(event:MouseEvent):void{
    removeChild(menubg);
    removeChild(menutitle);
    removeChild(day1click);
    removeChild(day2click);
    removeChild(day3click);
    removeChild(day4click);
    removeChild(day5click);
    removeChild(day6click);
    removeChild(day7click);
    day1click.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickMenu1);
    day2click.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickMenu2);
    day3click.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickMenu3);
    day4click.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickMenu4);
    day5click.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickMenu5);
    day6click.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickMenu6);
    day7click.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickMenu7);
    gotoAndStop('day6');
}

day7click.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickMenu7);
function onClickMenu7(event:MouseEvent):void{
    removeChild(menubg);
    removeChild(menutitle);
    removeChild(day1click);
    removeChild(day2click);
    removeChild(day3click);
    removeChild(day4click);
    removeChild(day5click);
    removeChild(day6click);
    removeChild(day7click);
    day1click.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickMenu1);
    day2click.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickMenu2);
    day3click.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickMenu3);
    day4click.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickMenu4);
    day5click.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickMenu5);
    day6click.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickMenu6);
    day7click.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickMenu7);
    gotoAndStop('day7');
}
```

Comment: Only exception is not helping much. Can you post the code through which you have created this multilevel menu?

Comment: Sure it is quite messy and I will clean it up once I get this working. Please check my edit to the main post:

Comment: You are adding menu level 2 , 3, 4 etc in main canvas only, i.e. this.add() but not in nested fashion. i.e. menu level 2 is not inside the menu level 2. Is that what you want to do? Or you need to add level 2 under level 1 and so on.

Comment: Essentially they are all meant to be displayed at the same time, here is how it looks visually:http://imgur.com/jedfwg7

Comment: Just last question...When you click on Day1 and then Day2 you get this exception.Click on Day2 button and then Day1 you will get same error. If so, then I have solution. Please let me know.

Comment: When I click Day1 it goes into the frame (day1) which has a door which the player must reach which then goes to another frame (day2), which works fine. You cannot get back to the menu again until you complete the 7 levels. So I can't test what you are asking. But if I click Day2 at the start menu it does not work no.

Comment: Sorry not able to figure out the exact issue but few suggestions are: 1. Just try to move all your addEventListner lines together and keep functions outside. 2. Keep all addevent listener in one function and then at the end of your click event handler pass the button name and add the listener. This must be some error related to adding and removing eventlistener and child sequence.

Answer (score 0):

trace every item where youre calling addChild()

example:

```
var childInstance:DisplayObject;
trace(childInstance);// if you see null then issue is found
addChild(childInstance);
```